# Can nginx handle duplicated HTTP headers?

Tags: nginx, httpserver, http-status-code-400

Client is sending requests with duplicated headers to server. Something like this:

```
GET /somefile.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT
```

Apache is handling this requests by concatenating all duplicating headers with ", ". So the resulting (handled) request will be like:

```
GET /somefile.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT, Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT, Tue, 31 Mar 2016 20:00:12 GMT
```

But nginx is returning code 400 (Bad Request). Now I can not modify client's behaviour. I need tmp solution on nginx server to handle these request (as Apache for example)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness check for the header "If-Unmodified-Since" is hardcoded (see [[1]](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#0087) [[2]](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#1573)). It cannot be disabled or dismissed, because Nginx validates headers during parsing, that is on a very early stage of request processing before any other handler or configuration option can intercept the process. So, the right answer would be no, unfortunately there is no proper way to make Nginx ignore this issue.

However, there is one dirty workaround. It exploits the fact that Nginx parses request headers only once and does not re-validate them after an internal redirect. This means that you can intercept the 400 error using [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) and then internally redirect the request to the same location:

```
# = is important here!
error_page 400 = @workaround;

location @workaround {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

But beware, for this is not how Nginx was meant to work and there are several serious drawbacks with this workaround:

1) Only the first value of "If-Unmodified-Since" will be passed to the backend.

2) Since Nginx stops parsing the request headers after it meets an error, no headers that come after "If-Unmodified-Since" will be passed to the backend at all.

The second drawback can actually be quite critical, so personally I would not recommend to use this method.

Comment: Thank you for explaining details. Seems like I'll have to switch to Apache for now...